# Update property binding from within a component

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular11

I have a simple custom dropdown component that I use in another (parent) component.

It all renders fine. But whenever I change the value of the dropdown by selectiing another option, then the value that is bound to the component is never updated.

My component looks like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  userId: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    if(!this.userId) {
      this.userId = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

And the html:

```js
<select [ngClass]="[sizeClass]" [(ngModel)]="userId">
  <option value="1">val 1</option>
  <option value="2">val 2</option>
</select>
```

And I use it in the parent component like this (app.component.html):

```js
<dropdown [(userId)]="appUserId"></dropdown>
<br><br>
<button (click)="saveData()">Save</button>
```

And in app.component.ts:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  appUserId: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appUserId = 1;
  }

  saveData(): void {
    // I expect appUserId to be changed, because I picked another value from the dropdown
    alert('selected userid = ' + this.appUserId);
  }
}
```

When I hit the save button it then shows that my property never gets updated.

## Demo app

I have an demo here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c3ew8a?file=src/app/dropdown/dropdown.component.html

### To reproduce:

- Load application.
- Select `val 2` from the dropdown
- Hit `Save` button.

I expect to see an alert showing the text `selected userid = 2`. But it shows: `selected userid = 1`. It never updated the `userId` property.

What do I have to do in Angular to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to use [two-ways data binding](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding) between app component and dropdown component the same as you use it between a component and it's own template.

It is possible to use two ways data binding between components but in order to do it you have supply the child component with an Input() (as you did) and emit an event from your child component with the same name as your input + 'Change' suffix. This event should contain the new value.

I forked your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shmp61?file=src/app/dropdown/dropdown.component.html) so you can see a working example as you wanted.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  userId: number;

  @Output() // Emit event with the same name of the input and 'Change' suffix 
  userIdChange = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit() {
    if(!this.userId) {
      this.userId = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select [ngClass]="[sizeClass]" [value]="userId" (change)="userIdChange.emit($event.target.value)"> <!-- $event.target is the target of the change event with is the select element) -->
  <option value="1">val 1</option>
  <option value="2">val 2</option>
</select>
```

[Reference](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#how-two-way-binding-works) from Angular docs